# mariadb json array of objects filter on property condition

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

Table `test_js` structure:

```
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
`json` JSON
```

Data:

```
`id`    `json`

`1`     `[{"id": 1, "size": 1, "ver": 0},{"id": 2, "size": 3, "ver": 1},{"id": 1, "size": 3, "ver": 2}]`
`2`     `[{"id": 1, "size": 3, "ver": 0}]`
`3`     `[{"id": 1, "size": 2, "ver": 3}]`
```

I need to return a filtered array of objects based on condition {"id": 1, "size": 3}

I try JSON_CONTAINS:

```
select `json` 
from `test_js` 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`json`, JSON_OBJECT("id", 1, "size", 3), '$');
```

and I get:

```
[{"id": 1, "size": 1, "ver": 0}, {"id": 2, "size": 3, "ver": 1}, {"id": 1, "size": 3, "ver": 2}]
[{"id": 1, "size": 3, "ver": 0}]
```

but I need like:

```
[{"id": 1, "size": 3, "ver": 2}]
[{"id": 1, "size": 3, "ver": 0}]
```

Is there any combination of JSON Functions to get the needed result?

current version - MariaDB 10.3.12

Comment: It illudes me as you can see  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=d3aa77ef71e929ef9cae3ea32c9de574  it doesn't workm perfectly because JSO_SEARCH doesn't search for twi vaules, One is no problem. So i stay by my opinion saving json xml html is idiotic as long there are no better function to seach and etract. Myslq has JSON_Table which could work, but mariadb hasn't it.

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=365e504e6e7d73267d231ae843ec4590).